# How to prevent React component mounting if props are empty?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component which works with third party library and I need to add listener after component mounts. For some reason I can't add listeners without data which asynchronously fetched from server and passed through 'connect' function (from react-redux).
How to prevent React component mounting if props are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I haven't found a solution, so I wrote mine:

```js
// No Props No Mount
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

function NPNM(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const { children } = this.props;
      const data = _.omit(this.props, children);
      let hasProps = true;

      _.forEach(data, elm => {
        if (_.isEmpty(elm) && !_.isFunction(elm)) hasProps = false;
      });

      return hasProps ? <WrappedComponent {...this.props} /> : <></>;
    }
  };
}

export default NPNM;
```

It should be used like

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NPNM(YourComponent));
```